# Convert Folders to VHD file

Tags: hyper-v, virtualization, copy, vhd, convert

I have a partition 200 GB contain 100 GB of Data, the Data is a huge number of files and folders (about million of files and folders). I want to copy this 100 GB of Data to another partition but i have a corruption because of the number of directories (Folders). As i know if i can convert these directories to one VHD file the problem can be resolved. The question is: How can i convert these directories to one VHD file?
I tried to create a VHD file and i attached it successfully from my Disk Management then i tried to copy the directories into but the huge number of folders and files cause a corrupted process so i want to create the VHD file from the Directories directly. Any Help !

Answer (score 1):

You should not have any kind of corruption due to the number of files involved in the copy process. If you suspect that you have a buggy application copying the files though, I suggest using something well-tested for bulk transfers like `robocopy`. Also consider that the volume / file system the files are on might be defective or damaged. A `chkdsk` run will help you determine and fix possible filesystem issues.

To answer your question, converting a (physical) disk to VHD can be done using the [***SysInternals' disk2vhd utility***](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx). Alternatively, doing a [Windows Server Backup](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732091.aspx) run to a local or networked destination also will create .vhd or .vhdx files (depending on your Windows Server version) with the contents of your disk(s).

Comment: I have used many application like XCOPY and ROBOCOPY and others but the huge number of folders and files cause a corruption.
what version of windows server can create the VHD or VHDX file?

Comment: As he has said above, the number of files isn't causing your corruption. If you want to create a VHD, you can use VirtualBox

Comment: If your files are corrupted, then they'll still be corrupted when you convert the volume to a VHD.  If they're not corrupted, then ROBOCOPY will work nicely.

Comment: @devices Windows Server Backup is available starting with Windows Server 2008. The disk2vhd utility will work on XP/Server 2003 as well. If you *have* tried using robocopy already, then I can assure you that it is not the "huge number of files and folders" causing the problems. I am copying large directories in the magnitude of 10 millions of files over some hundred thousand directories with robocopy occasionally - it works out nicely. You might want to start a new question with some details on commands you are using and the error message you are getting.